# Disable Angular rebuild

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

How to disable the rebuild after a file modification when using `ng serve` angular-cli command? Is it possible view the modifications only with the refresh of the page?

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are asking. Please rephrase and make it more clear what you are saying

Comment: the way ng serve works is, enable watch on file changes (which means whenever you make any changes it will be picked and rebuild) and adding a live reload which reload the page for any changes. You can stop loading the page by setting the flag (as NarrowVisionPlusMe suggested below) and to stop watching the files so that for any changes it doen't pick up the changes you can run the command like "ng serve --live-reload false --watch false" this command will not load browser also will not pick up any changes and not showing any logs in command line window

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ?

‘ng serve --live-reload false’

Comment: Yes, i did. But on the terminal happens to recharge. Can you understand me?

Comment: can you explain a bit more what do you mean by "happens to recharge"?

Comment: I am trying to understand your issue, could you provide little more  information.                                    Out of curiosity, why do you need to disable this feature?

Comment: Sorry. Happens to recharge == perform rebuild, webpack reload, chunk modules, etc...

Comment: The code of application is very large. Rebuild is too long.

Comment: Do you use angular CLI, if yes is it updated to latest version?

Comment: Yes, i do. Updated ok.